# How are cryptocurrencies transferred between different networks?

Tags: blockchain, bitcoin, cross-chain

I am new to blockchain and I have read some articles about coins, smart contract, tokens, etc. What I don't understand is that how I can send coin cross different networks. For example, I have a Bitcoin and I'd like to change it to Eth. Is there a way for me to exchange this two cryptocurrency?

If yes, how does the two different networks work together to complete this transaction.

If not, do I have to transfer Bitcoin to my bank account then purchase Eth later?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few different ways to do this, one way would be like you described, selling Bitcoin and transferring the money to your bank account, and then purchasing Ethereum.

On a Decentralized Exchange, you would need to use a method called [Atomic swaps](https://www.investopedia.com/terms/a/atomic-swaps.asp), which use something known as [Hashed Time-Locked Contracts](https://medium.com/liquality/hash-time-locked-contracts-htlcs-explained-e88aa99cc824).

These contracts involve the creation of a "pre-image", this pre-image is hashed using a [hashing function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_function) to create a "[hashlock](https://blog.liquality.io/hash-time-locked-contracts-htlcs-explained/#hashlocks-explained)". Users will have to agree upon a price, amount to swap, a time limit/deadline, and lock their tokens, once the pre-image is shared with the recipient to prove the sender is the owner of the funds both parties can withdraw the tokens. You can read more about them [here](https://cointelegraph.com/explained/what-is-an-atomic-swap-and-how-does-it-work), [here](https://www.coindesk.com/tech/2021/08/20/a-beginners-guide-to-atomic-swaps/) and [here](https://trustmachines.co/learn/bitcoin-atomic-swaps-how-they-work/#:%7E:text=Atomic%20swaps%20are%20peer%2Dto,need%20for%20a%20third%20party.).

If a user wants to swap a token for the same token on a different network there are a couple more ways they can do this, the first way is through a mint/burn structure. This involves burning x tokens on chain A, in order to mint x tokens on chain B. The second flow is very similar but instead of burning and minting, the tokens are simply locked and unlocked inside smart contracts. One example of a protocol that creates cross-chain tokens is called [LayerZero](https://layerzero.gitbook.io/docs/).

Another way would be to use a Centralized Exchange, which is most likely just a mix of matching your buy/sell order with another buy/sell order and updating balances internally.